# @aws-amplify dependency issue with vite build

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, vite

I'm currently working on converting our React project over to use Vite. It is great for development so far but when we try to run `vite build` (npm run build), we run into the following issue with `@aws-amplify`

```
[commonjs--resolver] Unexpected token (97:27) in /Users/directoryPlaceholder/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/vendor/paho-mqtt.js
file: /Users/directoryPlaceholder/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/vendor/paho-mqtt.js:97:27
95:   }
96: })(this, function LibraryFactory() {
97:   var PahoMQTT = (function (global) {
                                ^
98:     // Private variables below, these are only visible inside the function closure
99:     // which is used to define the module.
```

Our `vite.config.js` already has the following configurations:

```
    define: {
        global: '({})',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
        },
    },
```

and in `index.html`, we have the following script:

```
<script>
  const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined";
  const isGlobal = () => typeof global !== "undefined";
  if (!isGlobal() && isBrowser()) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this we would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this option from `vite.config.ts` fixed the issue

```
 define: {
        global: '({})',
    },
```